# Seed User and Role on Linux ARM - MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I'm use this code to seed user admin and role.
It's run smooth on local Windows computer and Mysql on server remote.
But when I deploy it to Ubuntu 20.04 ARM, seed data don't create.

ContextSeed.cs

```
public static class ContextSeed
{
    public static async Task SeedRolesAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
    {
        //Seed Roles
        await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(eRoles.SuperAdmin.ToString()));
    }

    public static async Task SeedSuperAdminAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
    {
        //Seed Default User
        var defaultUser = new ApplicationUser
        {
            UserName = "host",
            Email = "xxx@gmail.com",            
            EmailConfirmed = true,
            PhoneNumberConfirmed = true,
            Birthday = new DateTime(1989,10,16)
        };
        if (userManager.Users.All(u => u.Id != defaultUser.Id))
        {
            var user = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(defaultUser.Email);
            if (user == null)
            {
                await userManager.CreateAsync(defaultUser, "yyy");
                await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(defaultUser, eRoles.SuperAdmin.ToString());
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```
 using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
    try
    {
        var context = services.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
        var userManager = services.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
        var roleManager = services.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
        await ContextSeed.SeedRolesAsync(userManager, roleManager);
        await ContextSeed.SeedSuperAdminAsync(userManager, roleManager);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {            
        logger.Error(ex, "An error occurred seeding the DB."+ ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: do you get any error or it simply does not get called?

Comment: Maybe try the EnsureCreated method? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/ensure-created#ensurecreated